# Создание таблицы с объектами json, которые взяты из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, json, key-value

Есть таблица с продуктами(молоко, хлеб, яйца и т.д.)
Есть таблица с заказами, в ней есть строка 'Корзина', в которой по идее через запятую в виде json будут выводится данные из таблицы с продуктами.
insert into заказы(корзина)...
А КАК РАБОТАТЬ С JSON ОБЪЕКТАМИ В БД НЕ ЗНАЮ, никогда не работал. Понимаю как без json это делать, нужно именно json!!!
Спасибо

Comment: в разных БД работа с JSON устроена по своему. Она может отличаться в MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle... более того в рамках одной БД в разных версиях они могут быть устроены по разному... Поэтому без указания всего этого помочь вам будет невозможно.

Comment: Плюс было бы неплохо узнать что именно Вы собираетесь делать с этим JSON'ом и какие именно операции вам нужно объяснить.

Comment: Не в тему, но фраза `Понимаю как без json это делать, нужно именно json` навевает некоторые сомнения. Я бы воздерживался от использования хранения в БД сериализованных данных, если можно этого не делать...

Comment: БД PostgreSQL 10, колонка с продуктами преобразуется в json, потом этот json вносится в таблицу Заказы, в колонку 'Корзина'

Comment: Идея такова, что есть приложение, которое подключено к БД, выбирается набор продуктов и вносится в таблицу 'Заказы'.